# Getting json from html with same name

Tags: python, json

I have issue with scraping page and getting json from it.
`<script type="text/x-magento-init">` inside is json that I'am trying to get but when I try with `.find('script',{'type':'text/x-magento-init'})`I recive first json that I don't need. My question is how to find the 8th json with that same name? There is no other name/id etc.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `re.findall()`, that will return to you a list of matches. Then to get the 8th element you can go by `result[7]`